# how to use values from external property files in spring xml configuration?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, security, configuration

I tryed to pull password from hibernate config to separate properies file.

### Initially I had this config:

```
...
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    ...
    <property name="username" value=root />
...
```

### After I wrote following

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:db.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
...
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    ...
    <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
...
```

in db.properties I wrote following:

```
username=root
```

I got following trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [db.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

file with configurationa and db.properties locates in same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the `classpath:` keyword and just use db.properties in the list.

Comment: are you getting the same error? If so,I'd play around with the location of the db.properties file witin the web-inf folder

Answer (score 0):

it working after:

1. put db.properties to src/main/resources
2. replace this configuration

   ${db.username}

with

```
${username}
```